# overlapping Metal Point primitives and blending

Tags: metal, metalkit

I am rendering Points primitives that overlap partially. The fragment shader shades parts of each Point primitive square transparent (solid center circle). A point primitive that does not overlap any other point primitive, shades as expected (the transparent areas of the square show the background).

When such a point primitive overlaps another point primitive, the behavior is a unexpected. specifically: the transparent area does not show the opaque color of the unlerlying points primitive, but instead clears it and shows the background color.

In other words, point primitives with a higher vertex ID number clear the previsously shaded fragments of point primitives with a lower vertex ID number.

The points primitives are encoded like this:

```
command_encoder.drawPrimitives(.Point, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: stroke.count)
```

And the vertex & fragment shaders looks like this:

```
vertex OutVertex vertex_func(constant InVertex* vertex_array [[buffer(0)]],
                          constant Uniforms& uniforms [[buffer(1)]],
                          uint vid [[vertex_id]]) {

    OutVertex out;
    InVertex in = vertex_array[vid];

    // transform vertex into NDC space
    out.position = uniforms.projection * float4(in.position.x, in.position.y, 0, 1);

    out.pointSize = 60;

    return out;
}

fragment float4 fragment_func(OutVertex vert [[stage_in]], float2 uv[[point_coord]]) {
    float2 uvPos = uv;

    uvPos.x -= 0.5f;
    uvPos.y -= 0.5f;

    uvPos *= 2.0f;

    float dist = sqrt(uvPos.x*uvPos.x + uvPos.y*uvPos.y);
    float circleAlpha = 1.0f-dist;

    half4 color = half4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    color *= circleAlpha;

    return float4(color.r, color.g, color.b, circleAlpha);
}
```

The results looks like this:

[image]
[image]

I would like to find out how to prevent the clearing of overlapping transparent areas but maintain the transparency against the background.

Thank you.

**Update 5/25/16:**

I was able to turn on fixed function blending with these additions to my render pipeline descriptor:

```
    rpld.colorAttachments[0].blendingEnabled = true
    rpld.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .Add;
    rpld.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .Add;
    rpld.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .One;
    rpld.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .One;
    rpld.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .OneMinusSourceAlpha;
    rpld.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .OneMinusSourceAlpha;
```

And now things look as expected:

[image]

Comment: How are you configuring your depth-stencil state object? It looks like you have depth write enabled, but you actually want it disabled. Also, depending on your blend function, you might need to sort points from far to near to get the desired effect (e.g., if you're using a non-associative blend function like SrcAlpha, 1-SrcAlpha).

Comment: Thank you, warrenm for your reply. Since i'm a absolute beginner at Metal, i don't know what you mean by "depth write enabled". How can i disable it? Also, im not setting any blend function, so i guess i am getting whatever is the default. In this use case, i don't care about depth, because all Point primitives are on the same Z depth from the camera. This is trying to port a brush stroke painting system from OpenGL to Metal.

Comment: Interesting, that's not the effect I would've expected with blending disabled, but I'm glad you found something that works for you.