# Repitition of texture on pan gesture in Metal Shading Language

Tags: swift, textures, metal, metalkit

I am new to metal shading language.So your kind guidance would be so helpful.
I just repeated texture using metal as shown on below image
[(Image sequence).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idqud.png)
But it seems not smoothy.How can I make it to be appeared as smoothy line as done in following link for metal points.([overlapping Metal Point primitives and blending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421212/overlapping-metal-point-primitives-and-blending))

At the moment what I do is allocating memory for vertex buffer (MTLBuffer) at each touch point in my gesture.

code:

```
func allocateMemoryForVetexBuffer(vertices: Array<Vertex>){
        var vertexData = Array<Float>()
        for vertex in vertices{
            vertexData += vertex.floatBuffer()
        }

        let dataSize = vertexData.count * MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: vertexData[0])
        print("dataSize:\(dataSize)")
        vertexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: vertexData, length: dataSize, options: [])

        vertexCount = vertices.count

    }
```

I am calling this method in my pan gesture recognizer.But it causes to drop FPS.So my problem is without knowing how many textures will add on single pan on metal layer, how may I allocate memory for Frame Buffer.

Comment: You're probably not going to be able to get around updating the buffer from the CPU side every time you get a touch event, but you could allocate a buffer that's large enough to accommodate, say, 64 quads, then double it in length when it fills up, drawing only the portion of the buffer that's actually populated.

Comment: tanks warrenm.it helps.I just allocate memory and copy newly arriving data into it.But when adding more & more textures FPS drops. What could be the reason for droping FPS?

Comment: Quantify: how many points/quads are you drawing, and what FPS do you achieve?

Comment: FPS:60 & one texture(image) contains 6 vertices. When touch moves it draws texture in each touch point. That means there can be thousands of points in my drawing.

Comment: I have added working project for your reference. https://github.com/kasunSithiraPalihakkara/metal-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're unnecessarily using instancing.

Change this:

```
renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: vertexCount, 
                             instanceCount: vertexCount / 3)
```

to this:

```
renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: vertexCount)
```

Comment: Thanks warrenm. It works. But at some point it shows an error.                        "Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Ignored (for causing prior/excessive GPU errors) (IOAF code 4)". So what would be the possible reason for this?

Comment: I saw that as well. I think you're causing the GPU to read outside the bounds of the buffer, once you pass a certain number of vertices. But I didn't investigate this very thoroughly.